# Distance calculation which is faster mongodb or mysql

Tags: php, mysql, performance, mongodb, database-performance

I am little bit confused about following problem & their solutions:
i have 2 tables `users` & `userfriends` having following structure

```
users
userid         lat          long


userfriends
    userid         friendid
```

so in users table i have lat & long of all the users & in userfriends i have list of friends for each user.
Now i want to calculate nearby users (distance) so my friend told me to use mongodb which have fast performance.
But i found another function which i can use in stored procedure in mysql

```
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) { 

  $theta = $lon1 - $lon2; 
  $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta)); 
  $dist = acos($dist); 
  $dist = rad2deg($dist); 
  $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  $unit = strtoupper($unit);

  if ($unit == "K") {
    return ($miles * 1.609344); 
  } else if ($unit == "N") {
      return ($miles * 0.8684);
    } else {
        return $miles;
      }
}
```

So basically i want my distance calculation faster & quick.
So can somebody tell me am i correct in my way or i need to send needed data (lat & long of users friends) to mongodb & calculate & mongodb will return results to my database (MySQL)?

Comment: I wouldn't use both DBS. Choose one and stick with it. The performance you gain from choosing the right DBS (if there is one) will definately be lost by transfereing data between them. I think MySQL will do fine with this problem. Just use some fitting indexes.

Comment: You will also not need to calculate the exact distance. There must be some heursitics to guess a vague distance that will calculate much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html) and [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing) support geospatial indexing. IME, NoSQL databases have huge performance advantages when dealing with selecting individual records, but offer less of a performance benefit (still usually faster) compared with a relational database when dealing with range queries - YMMV.

There are other very fundamental differences - which are well covered elsewhere.

You really want to spend a lot of time reading the linked documents - the method you describe will be phenomonally innefficient.

Comment: I am going to use MongoDB as its also calculate distance for me in just few miliseconds. Thanks for your answer